# KeyError: 'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, youtube, pytube

I am trying to make a code which can download the entire playlist from YouTube. It worked for some playlist but not working for few playlists. One of the playlist I have shown in my code below. Also feel free to add more features on this code.
If there is already a code to download the playlist so please share the link with me

`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pytube import YouTube
import urllib.request
import time
import os


## list of link parsed by bs4
s = []


## to name and save the playlist folder and download path respectively 
directory = 'Hacker101'
savePath = "G:/Download/video/"
path = os.path.join(savePath, directory)


## link parser
past_link_here = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxhvVyxYRviZd1oEA9nmnilY3PhVrt4nj"
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(past_link_here)
x = html_page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    k = link.get('href')
    if 'watch' in k:
        s.append(k)
    else:
        pass


## to create playlist folder
def create_project_dir(x):
    if not os.path.exists(x):
        print('Creating directory ' + x)
        os.makedirs(x)
create_project_dir(path)


## downloading videos by using links from list s = []
for x in set(s):
    link="https://www.youtube.com" + x
    yt = YouTube(link)
    k = yt.title
    file_path = path + '\\' + k + '.mp4'
    try:
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            print(k + ' is \n' + "already downloaded")
        else:
            j = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True).all()
            l = yt.streams.first()
            print(k + ' is downloading....')
            l.download(path)
            time.sleep(1)
            print('downloading compleat')

##    except Exception:
##        print('error')

    except KeyError as e:
        print('KeyError') % str(e)
```

`

[image]

Comment: This is fixed in pytube3 https://github.com/hbmartin/pytube3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue appears to be related to a bug that was fixed today by [giacaglia](https://github.com/giacaglia) . Based on the [Github Commit](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/pull/534/commits/e5f1a9e2476b096ed2012939d50851d3499016e1) the solution to the bug can be fixed by modifying your mixins.py as detailed in the link. Your playlists should work without running into the KeyError: 'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map' issue you had above.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked this question before the release of new version of pytube this problem is solved in pytube3 you just need to install it by using pip cmd i.e `pip install pytube3`

Answer (score 0):

kindly check out this doc [pytube3](https://pypi.org/project/pytube3/) ive used the methods in it and it has actually worked..
the first step is basically to upgrade the pytube library :
 `pip3 install pytube3 --upgrade`
the load your code next...
for the normal youtube video downlaods:

```
from pytube import YouTube
url = input("Paste the URL here -->>")
yt = YouTube(url)
YouTube(url).streams[0].download()
```

for the whole playlist

```
from pytube import Playlist

url = input("Paste the URL here -->>")
playlist = Playlist(url)
for my_videos in playlist:
     my_videos.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
```

have Fun make something cool!!!